# Closed form formula for the following definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I ran into the following family of logarithmic trignometric integrals:
$$ F(t) := \frac{3}{2\pi^3} \int_0^{2\pi} \log(2(1 + cos \theta)) \log(2 (1 + \cos(\theta + t))) d\theta.$$
It appears $F(0) = 1$ and $F(\pi) = -1/2$. I am wondering if it has closed form formula for other values of $t$. Through the central limit theorem, this is closely related to [this interesting probability problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35510/maximum-of-polynomials-in-the-unit-circle).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$\log(2(1+\cos x))=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cos nx}{n}.$$
Hence
$$\eqalign{\log(2(1+\cos \theta))&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cos n\theta}{n}\cr
\log(2(1+\cos (\theta+t))&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cos nt}{n}\cos n\theta-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\sin nt}{n}\sin n\theta
}$$
Using Bessel-Parseval we see that the considered integral can be written as follows
$$\forall\,t\in [0,2\pi],~F(t)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos n t}{n^2}=
1 - \frac{3}{\pi}t + \frac{3}{2\pi^2} t^2.$$
The last equality follows from the well-known expansion in fourier series of Bernoulli Polynomials, for more details see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliPolynomial.html).

Comment: Well done! (+1)